# tap on notification in ios 13 containg appdelgate and scenedelegate not working

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios13

I have tried this in ios 13 project this is not working.I have to move from appdelegate to another controller in storyboard

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { 
        
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginPageView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leadBidderPagerID") as! LeadBidderPage
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        rootViewController.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
    completionHandler()
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The window variable is not available anymore in AppDelegate, which
   is moved to SceneDelegate instead.
2. But the function that will be called when push notification is
   tapped is still in App Delegate, because push notification tap is
   app-wide, which is not limited to just one scene
3. The main goal is to access the window.rootViewController from
   AppDelegate so we can change the structure of current view
   controllers presented to user.
4. In order to access the window property as defined in
   SceneDelegate.swift file, we need to cast it to SceneDelegate using
   as? SceneDelegate .

```swift
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    // the root view controller 
    
    guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else { return } 
    
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    let loginPageView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leadBidderPagerID") as! LeadBidderPage
    
    if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? PTTabbarVC, let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController { navController.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true) 
    } 
    
    completionHandler() 
    }
```

You can refer this tutorial , [https://fluffy.es/open-app-in-specific-view-when-push-notification-is-tapped-ios-13](https://fluffy.es/open-app-in-specific-view-when-push-notification-is-tapped-ios-13/)/